# iOS - Enterprise Development Program - Certificate Expired

Tags: ios, deployment, certificate, enterprise

My iOS app (registered with '**Apple Enterprise Development Program**) certificate is expired yesterday.

I've renewed it today but still my existing app is not working in iPhone device.

I've gone through several questions/answers on Stackover Flow and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768895/ios-enterprise-deployment-expiration) ([iOS Enterprise Deployment / Expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768895/ios-enterprise-deployment-expiration)) useful but it's three years old. And there so many changes have been made by Apple Inc.

My question is:

> Do I need to create a new build (IPA) and share it to all users again?

or Is there any way to reactivate existing app without updating?

Comment: Do I need to create a new build (IPA) and share it to all users again? - YES!

Comment: Interesting issue. I haven't ever faced it since my apps have been always under developing or I just stop care about them. In which way the experied certificate issue prevents app from working? Does it cause the app crash, or show some dialig? I will really apreciate any details, thanks.

Comment: Yes, app is crashing. Not allowing me to launch an app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Un)fortunately - There is no way to swap the code signature on the fly since it could have been heavily exploited.

I guess you do not need to make any new build, just resign the existing IPA with a renewed certificate.

If updating the app for all the users is a bigger issue for you, you can check if MDM-based solution can be applied - https://support.apple.com/business

Using MDM you can manage multiple devices at once, so reinstalling the app shouldn't take much time.

Comment: Your answer seems correct but looking for more effective solution that do not require to update an app. Pl. suggest me any way to do it without updating existing app.

Comment: There is no other solution I'm afraid. You need the certificate to be valid. You cannot swap it on the fly without the whole distribution process run again. If you manage to do so, please contact the FBI since they may be interested in such a skill :P

Try using MDM in the next iteration so it won't be that painful